# I have a vba code to schedule teams meeting from excel file, but it does not take the date and time from the excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following vba code, which [image: excel file screenshot] takes the data from the excel file, but the meetins are created with current date and time. Can someone help me please?

```
Sub SetApptWithHTMLContent()
    Dim olapp As Object
    Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Dim appt As Object
    Dim ml1 As Worksheet
    Set ml1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Message")
    
    Dim supermessage As String
    supermessage = ml1.Range("B4").Value
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scheduler")
    
    Dim r As Long
    r = 2
    
    Do While Len(sh.Cells(r, 10).Value) > 5
        Set appt = olapp.CreateItem(1) ' olAppointmentItem
        
        With appt
            .Subject = sh.Cells(r, 4).Value & " " & sh.Cells(r, 2).Value
            .MeetingStatus = olMeeting ' Set the appointment to be a meeting
            
            ' Start date from column G with time set to 09:00:00
            If IsDate(sh.Cells(r, 7).Value) Then
                .Start = CDate(sh.Cells(r, 7).Value) + TimeValue("10:00:00")
            End If
            
            ' End date from column G with time set to 09:30:00
            If IsDate(sh.Cells(r, 7).Value) Then
                .End = CDate(sh.Cells(r, 7).Value) + TimeValue("10:30:00")
            End If
            
            .Location = sh.Cells(r, 1).Value
            .Recipients.Add sh.Cells(r, 10).Value ' Add the required attendees
            
            ' Include any optional attendees if applicable
            If Len(sh.Cells(r, 12).Value) > 0 Then
                .OptionalAttendees = sh.Cells(r, 12).Value
            End If
            
            ' Add the body or HTML content if needed
            .Body = supermessage
            
            ' Display the meeting for review
            .Display
        End With
        
        ' Increment to the next row for processing
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

i expect the macro to take date and time from excel to schedule the meeting

Comment: Does `IsDate(sh.Cells(r, 7).Value) ` return true when you are in debug mode?

Comment: Yes I can see that in debug mode